# Sorting Multidimensional Array by Specific Key

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

**EDIT**: For anyone who might come across this post with a similar problem, It was solved by taking **konforce**'s supplied answer and tweaking around a bit with the custom sorting function:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a[5] == $b[5]) {
        return ($a[3] < $b[3]) ? -1 :1;
    }
    return ($a[5] > $b[5]) ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Notice `$a[5] == $b[5]` does not return zero. It was changed to check who has the most losses and then sort it in ASC order. I'm sure you can even keep going and add another if-statement in there in-case they have the same losses.

Lastly, all you do is `usort($ARRAY, "cmp");` and finito!!!

**Original Post**

My apologies for coming up with yet another MD Array sorting question but I'm just not getting it. I've searched aplenty
for a solution and although many sites have provided what seemed like a logical answer I still have not been able to figure it out.

My problem is since I'm still learning its been rather difficult for me to grasp the concept of using usort with a custom comparing
function. Atleast, thats what I have seen the most when others have tried to sort MD Arrays.

I'm working on a small project to sharpen up on my php skills. Its a very basic tournament standings script that holds a team's information within an array. I would like to sort the array by most points($array[X][X][5]).

So the array looks something like this:

```
Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [0] => cooller
                [1] => 6 
                [2] => 6 
                [3] => 0 
                [4] => 0 
                [5] => 18 
            )
        ) 
        [1] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [0] => strenx 
                [1] => 9 
                [2] => 5 
                [3] => 1 
                [4] => 3 
                [5] => 18
            )
        )
        [2] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [0] => rapha
                [1] => 10
                [2] => 8
                [3] => 1
                [4] => 1
                [5] => 25
            )
        ) [3] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [0] => ronald reagan
                [1] => 5 
                [2] => 4 
                [3] => 0 
                [4] => 1 
                [5] => 13
            )
        )
    )
```

I would like to sort it by most points(cell #5), so it would look like this **after** sorting:

```
Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [0] => rapha
                [1] => 10
                [2] => 8
                [3] => 1
                [4] => 1
                [5] => 25
            )
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [0] => cooller
                [1] => 6 
                [2] => 6 
                [3] => 0 
                [4] => 0 
                [5] => 18 
            )
        ) 
        [2] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [0] => strenx 
                [1] => 9 
                [2] => 5 
                [3] => 1 
                [4] => 3 
                [5] => 18
            )
        )
        [3] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [0] => ronald reagan
                [1] => 5 
                [2] => 4 
                [3] => 0 
                [4] => 1 
                [5] => 13
            )
        )
    )
```

The player with 25 points would be at the top, followed by 18, 18, and lastly 13. Sorry for my earlier post, was having difficulty wording my question correctly. Thanks in advanced!

Comment: If your arrays are numerically indexed anyway, why do you bother using this syntax, `array(0 => value)`?

Comment: Some oddities here: `for ($i=0; $i<=0;...)` There's no need for a loop... you are hardcoding the value `$i=0`. You are passing by reference when you should just be returning the new array. Your functions shouldn't have to know quite so much about the incoming data (i.e., the whole `if ($groupNum == 0)` bit at the end).

Comment: PS: The most useful thing in terms of getting a good answer is to provide the exact array's contents as seen from `print_r` at the moment it is supposed to be sorted... and then a second copy of how you expect it to look after.

Comment: What do the first and second indexes mean? I don't yet understand how you want the array to be sorted.

Comment: @Keoki - I've no idea. That was the format I saw a lot when researching MD Arrays...


@konforce - I don't quite understand... but I will be editing my OP when I get home. Perhaps using `print_r` will help those not quite understanding what I'm trying to achieve. So hang tight!

Comment: @lemonpole, I've updated my answer to work with the arrays given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
usort($standings, function($a, $b) { return $b[0][5] - $a[0][5]; });
```

Or prior to PHP 5.3:

```
function cmp($a, $b) { return $b[0][5] - $a[0][5]; }
usort($standings, 'cmp');
```

When using `usort`, the `$a` and `$b` parameters will be one "layer" into the supplied array. So in your case, an example of `$a` or `$b` will be:

```
[0] => Array (
         [0] => cooller
         [1] => 6 
         [2] => 6 
         [3] => 0 
         [4] => 0 
         [5] => 18 
)
```

I'm not sure why you have an extra containing array there, but as you can see, you want to sort based on the `[0][5]` position.

Comment: Yea I think its the statement `$standings[] = array($i => array("$name", $games, $win, $loss, $draw, $points));` found within my for-loop. I'm going to test this out ASAP and i'll let you know whats up. Thanks for your help. :]

Comment: okay so i changed my previous statement to eliminate that extra array; so as you stated above it is now based on position `[0][5]`. I used your method with `usort` and the custom compare function. There has been sorting but not in DESC order. I got, `13, 25, 18, 18`... I was thinking would a loop within the compare function help it read through all the values and compare them? So it would be based on position `[$i][5]` for example.

Comment: Hey, just letting you know I solved the problem by tweaking your sorting function a bit. I updated my OP with the solution. :] thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`usort($standings[0][0][5], 'cmp')` won't work because the first parameter isn't an array to sort, it's just a single number, the points.